# Sort based on associated points in rails4

Tags: ruby, postgresql, associations, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

**Post model**

```
has_many :votes
```

**Vote model**

```
belongs-to :post
```

I need to fetch all posts from posts table and to display. But the entries should be sorted in ASC/DESC(params[:order]) of its votes. If all posts have Vote table entry then below code works perfectly.

I have a query as below:

```
@posts = Post.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id').select('posts.*, SUM(votes.point) AS total_point').group('posts.id').order("total_point #{params[:order]}")
```

But, if any post have no votes table entry, then the non-voted posts makes the list sorting appear wrong. If no votes to some posts, and if the sort order is ASC ,then need to appear the non-voted posts first in the list , and 
if the sort order is DESC ,then need to appear the non-voted posts last in the list. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause not all of your posts have votes then after join some records will have `votes.point` value as a `NULL`. `NULL`s are specific values which should be handled separately and may cause issues with descending ordering, because they are sorted last in default ascending order in PostgreSql. In order to have records with `NULL` votes properly sorted I would suggest to coerce `NULL` values to 0.

```
SUM(COALESCE(votes.point, 0))
```

After that all posts which don't have votes will have `total_point` value equal to 0 which is a regular number that can be ordered as you want.

Alternatively, PostgreSql has additional syntax for specifying how `NULL` values should be sorted with `ORDER BY` clause.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY
Example:

```
ORDER BY somevalue DESC NULLS LAST
```